# camera setup in ray tracing in c

Tags: c, graphics, raytracing

i set up a camera in ray tracing but when i trying to draw sphere, the object goes away from the origin even if i put camera at 0.0.0 origin,

that's my code:

```
t_camera    camera(t_canvas *canvas, t_scene *sc)
{
    t_camera    cam;
    double      focal_len;
    double      viewport_height;

    viewport_height = tan(sc->cam.fov * 13.14 / 180);
    focal_len = 1.0;
    cam.orig = sc->cam.cen;
   cam.viewport_h = viewport_height;
   cam.viewport_w = viewport_height * canvas->aspect_ratio;
   cam.focal_len = focal_len;
   cam.horizontal = make_vec(cam.viewport_w, 0, 0);
   cam.vertical = make_vec(0, cam.viewport_h, 0);
   // left corner, origin - horizontal / 2 - vertical / 2 - vec3(0,0,focal_length)
   cam.left_bottom = sub_vec(sub_vec(sub_vec(cam.orig, div_vect(cam.horizontal, 2)),
                            div_vect(cam.vertical, 2)), make_vec(0, 0, focal_len));
   return (cam);
}
```

sub_vec is subtraction of vector and div_vect is dividing a vector,
can any one please help.

Comment: How are your rays being generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix my problem, and the final code if someone needs it:

```
typedef struct Camera_Setup
{
    t_vec       orig;
    t_vec       up;
    t_vec       right;
    t_vec       forward;
    double      height;
    double      width;
    double      aspect_r;
    double      theta;
}   t_camera;

t_camera    set_camera(t_scene *sc)
{
    t_camera    cam;

    cam.orig = sc->cam.cen;
    cam.aspect_r = (double) WIDTH / (double) HEIGHT;
    cam.theta = sc->cam.fov * M_PI / 180.0;
    cam.height = tan(cam.theta / 2);
    cam.width = cam.aspect_r * cam.height;
    cam.forward = sc->cam.dir;
    cam.forward.x += EPS;
    cam.up = get_normalized(vect_cross(cam.forward, 
               make_vec(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)));
    cam.right = get_normalized(vect_cross(cam.forward, 
                  cam.up));
    return (cam);

}
```

for the (t_scene *sc) its the objects scene.

The source:

[camera ray tracing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRN_ewuN_k4&t=3s)

[Placing a Camera: the LookAt Function](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/mathematics-physics-for-computer-graphics/lookat-function)

Answer (score 0):

```
viewport_height = tan(sc->cam.fov * 13.14 / 180);
```

Perhaps I am missing something, but if this is transforming to rads, shouldn't it be `3.14 / 180`?

Comment: thanks, that's one of the mistakes.